# Delphi dbGo in Web Service

Tags: windows, delphi, soap, ado

I am trying to build a SOAP server that retrieves data from a SQL Server backend.  I am using Delphi 10.4 Community Edition and ADO to connect to the database.  I get the following error: CoInitialize was not called.  I understand that this is probably because the Web Service is multithreaded and threads need this function to be called.

I know that DataSnap is probably preferred for this but I really want to use ADO.

My question is where to call this function as the TThread object is not exposed in the Web Module.  Also, should I place the TADOTable component on a DataModule or is it ok to put in the WebModule?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a SOAP server specifically, when a REST server is even more functional. You can use any database access components in any ServerMethodsUnits that you add to your REST server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I am using SOAP because REST Server Isn't available in the Community Edition, unless I missed something.  There is support for creating REST Clients but I need both.

Ultimately I will need to upload/download files and DataSets.  I got the file transfer to work using TSOAPAttachment.  I was going to export the Dataset as an XML File and transfer that as a file.  Everytime I accessed the SOAP Server after adding ADO Components it returned an error indicating that I needed to call CoInitialize.

Comment: If this is a poor strategy I will concede the point.  If someone has a good tutorial/book/example of how to use the SOAPDataModule that would be useful as well.

Comment: It is not a poor strategy. SOAP servers are still used today. There are plenty of Delphi SOAP tutorials on the Web. Every year, Embarcadero includes bug fixes for the SOAP server components in the new release.

Comment: You have hit on the very reasons I chose SOAP.  I would have preferred REST as it seems like it is the next best thing and if I am every required to create another Web Server my skills should be concentrated there.

BTW, I was able to successfully integrate the TSOAPDatamodule into my test bed application.  It doesn't connect to SQL Svr yet but it does return the current server time as a string.

Comment: Thanks Freddie.  I was able to connect to the WebService and retrieve both files and datasets.  I think the trick was to put all of the DB Stuff in the SOAPDataModule.  I was able to ADODB to connect to the SQL Server and retrieve records.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Freddie. I was able to connect to the WebService and retrieve both files and datasets. I think the trick was to put all of the DB Stuff in the SOAPDataModule. I was able to ADODB(dbGO) to connect to the SQL Server and retrieve records.

Answer (score 1):

I'm primarily a database developer. I have some go-to's I settled on donkeys years ago and most of my work focuses on the stuff I already know how to use (C++Builder, MSSQL, & dbGo).

From the bits I've picked up...

I've developed a number of service applications that use dbGo and this is where I learned about CoInitialize. You don't come across this in normal applications as CoInitialize is taken care of Automatically by Embarcadero. However, per MS documentation this call initializes the COM library **on the current thread**; so you learn about CoInitialize the same day you learn about creating threads...

For me this was when I started working with Service Applications. For Services, it seems most advice suggests not using the 'OnExecute' event, but to instead create a Thread that is started in the 'OnStart' event and Terminated in the 'OnStop' event. So, I too had issues with ADO, threads & CoInitialize.

I found that where I used CoInitialize had an impact on whether it would work correctly. If I recall I tried using CoInitialize in the obvious place (The thread constructor) but this did not work. The place that did work is **'at the start of the TMyThread::Execute () block'**.

Note : You also need to call CoUninitialize once, for each time you have called CoInitialize. To make instance tracking easier I tend to create an object that calls CoInitialize (once) for me .. and calls CoUninitialize (once) for me when it's cleaned up.

Here's an example : Unfortunately for you. I use C++ Builder rather than Delphi, but the principles work the same so this should hopefully help

```
TSimple_COMInitialise::TSimple_COMInitialise  ( void )
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL,COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
}
TSimple_COMInitialise::~TSimple_COMInitialise ( void )
{
    CoUninitialize();
}

void __fastcall TWorkerThread_CCSync::Execute ()
{
                                 // ( 'A Message' , show a timestamp )
    this->SendSynchronisedFeedbackl (L"Thread::Begin Execution", true); 
    // I use a pointer to a bool value so external threads can monitor 
    // when the thread is running 
    // apparently you can also use MyThreadObject->CheckTerminated(); externally
    this->_SetRunningStatus (true);
    // create an object that calls CoInitialize
    TSimple_COMInitialise   *ptr_Thread_COMInitialise = new TSimple_COMInitialise();  
    __try
    {
        while (!this->Terminated)                                           
        {                                                                   
            //---- Add a wait/delay here ( to CPU usage reasonable ) ----
            TThread::Sleep (this->ExecutePeriod);
            // request records from the SQL server and iterate through...           
            this->DoWork_PROCESS_RECORDS();
            this->DoWork_CALL_A_DIFFERENT_ADO_PROCEDURE();
            if (this->Terminated)
            {
                this->SendSynchronisedFeedback (L"Thread::User Terminated", true); 
            }

        }
    }__finally
    {
        // if this object in initiualised ... CoInitialize() was called
        if (ptr_Thread_COMInitialise)
        {
            // This will call CoUnInitialize()
            delete ptr_Thread_COMInitialise;                                             
        };

    }
    // let the main app know 'execute' has fully terminated/ended
    this->_SetRunningStatus (false);
    this->SendSynchronisedFeedback (L"Thread::End Execution", true); 
}
```

In my current project I've had to compartmentalise some 3rd party components to avoid them blowing eachother up with incompatibilities. I've encapsulated them in DataModules...so I don't know that using data modules is an answer (I'm currently having problems with my 'dbGo DataModule').

Perhaps a SOAP DataModule has some Embarcadero CoInitialize magic woven in??
Notwithstanding, I can't find this in order to add it to my project, so maybe it's availability is project type dependent. In which case, for anybody not able to use a SOAP Module...I hope this helps.